# Parallel Computing in the cloud

Tags: parallelization, high-performance-clusters

I'm currently processing a large dataset created from a search log of around 2.5 million entries using association rule mining. The pre-processing of the data alone to extract entities from the search terms is taking hours if not days, and seems an ideal candidate to run on a cluster. Wolfram describes a large number of use cases for such, but not beyond running gridMathematica or similar on a managed Linux cluster. A more typical setup seems to be ten or so instances on a network in a lab.

I've enquired at work if we could setup such a small network, but I'm being strongly pushed in the direction of AWS. So has anyone successfully run up a Mathematica grid on the likes of Amazon Cloud, with an off cloud instance fronting the cluster? And if so what are the challenges, technical or financial?